# Recylerview items only registering clicks sometimes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've a `Recylerview` with an `ImageView` & a `TextView`. I have a `snankbar` message that is displayed when either of these are clicked. The problem is, is that I have to click many times to for the snackbar message to be displayed its is as if only a few pixels are clickable.

**EDIT** [Here is an example in action (ignore the background audio)](https://youtu.be/_7GpS1fJK6U) - I am spamming clicks at the beginning of this video then you will notice I slow down and after that every time I move my cursor it is a click, but you can see the majority don't register.

Why would this be?

Here is the `Activity` looks (clearly the clickable areas are large enough):

[image]

Here is the Recycler set-up:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    ArrayList<CreateList> createLists = prepareData();
    adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), createLists);
    adapter.setClickListener(mainActivity);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is the relevant adapter code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.title.setText(galleryList.get(i).getImage_title());
    viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    File imgFile = new File(galleryList.get(i).getImage_ID());
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    viewHolder.img.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return galleryList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    public TextView title;
    public ImageView img;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        this.title = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        this.img = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        Log.i("PRINT", "HIT ON CLICK");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Recycle Click" + "on position " + getAdapterPosition() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And finally the `RecyclerItemRow` xml:

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/images_bg"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_image_not_supported_24"
    android:textColor="@color/headerColors"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Image_title"
    android:textColor="@color/headerColors"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Next"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Next"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_navigate_next_24"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Why would this be?

Comment: what's the method `setClickListener` ( `adapter.setClickListener(mainActivity);`)? Maybe try to remove it and check

Comment: this is a method where I set the listener from the `MainActivity` I have a method for this and call it in place of the line `adapter.setClickListener(mainActivity);`, Rather than show this in the `MainActivity` code i replaced it for this sake of keeping this Q shorter.

Comment: assign a `id `to the parent layout and set onClickListener() for that id instead of the `view`.

Comment: @Vatsalkesarwani no joy.

Comment: Not sure if your problem is resolved or not. But on side note you should not be using `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` on main thread . Instead use an Image loader lib probably Glide or Picasso whichever fine for you .

Comment: @ADM - noted, cheers. Original problem remains unresolved.